# For Loop in Stored Procedure (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to make a stored procedure to insert employees monthly salary in there payroll table. can anybody give example?

There are two tables

```
Employees (EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeStatus, BasicSalary)
```

and

```
EmployeePayroll (PayrollID, EmployeeID, VoucherNo, BasicSalary, SalaryMonth)
```

1. Get Total Employees From Employees Table WHERE EmployeeStatus IN ('Active')............for example let's say (50 employees)

   Make a Loop for all these 50 employees and Insert salary payment voucher in table (EmployeePayroll).

   In EmployeePayroll table it will be inserted with auto generated voucher no for example:

```
SET @PayrollID = (SELECT MAX(PayrollID) AS PayrollID FROM HR.EmployeePayroll)
SET @VoucherNo = ('SPV-K-' + CAST(DATEPART(YY,GETDATE())AS VARCHAR) + CAST(DATEPART(MM,GETDATE())AS VARCHAR) + CAST(DATEPART(DD,GETDATE())AS VARCHAR) + '-00' + @PayrollID)
```

So records will be like following:

```
PayrollID.......EmployeeID.......VoucherNo......BasicSalary.........SalaryMonth
1..................1...........SPV-K-11501-001.....250..................1
2..................2...........SPV-K-11501-002.....300..................1
3..................3...........SPV-K-11501-004.....400..................1
```

Comment: PayrollID = 3 has voucher "SPV-K-11501-004"? That doesn't match your logic... Also, you shouldn't calculate PayRollID: it should be IDENTITY. And where does SalaryMonth come from? Finally, what have you tried so far?

Comment: just a quick note that creating loops in sql is generally bad practice as it doesn't use set based approches

Comment: Also the names for the salary columns in the payroll are irritating. You only pay 1$ although they should have received 300? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for insert operations that get their data from other tables. As gbn suggested make the voucherID an IDENTITY column so it autoincrements on each insert. Then use an insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeePayroll (EmployeeID, VoucherNo, BasicSalary, SalaryMonth)
SELECT 
    EmployeeID, 
    ( 'SPV-K-' + 'rest of your voucher calculation'),
    BasicSalary, 1
FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeStatus IN ('Active')
```

Note that integrating the voucher-ID into the voucher-number is not possible this way and also desirable, IMHO. A better way would be to save the current date as a column "payout-day" and then generate the voucher number when selecting from this table. (Or better create a view for reading from this table and put the "VoucherNo" calculation into that views SELECT statement)